# Input type Range showing textbox instead of slider

Tags: forms, html, mobile-website

Here is my code:

```
<input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="5" min="0" max="10" step="1" />
```

All HTML5 mobile browsers I have tested this in (iPhone 4, Android, iPad) render this as input type=text. Why won't this render a slider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all browsers support it yet. You can always use http://www.modernizr.com/ to test if the browser supports it and then use http://jqueryui.com/ as a fallback. Try something like this.

```js
var initSlider = function() {  
    $('input[type=range]').each(function() {  
        var $input = $(this);  
        var $slider = $('<div id="' + $input.attr('id') + '" class="' + $input.attr('class') + '"></div>');  
        var step = $input.attr('step');  

        $input.after($slider).hide();  

        $slider.slider({  
            min: $input.attr('min'),  
            max: $input.attr('max'),  
            step: $input.attr('step'),  
            change: function(e, ui) {  
                $(this).val(ui.value);  
            }  
        });  
    });  
};
```

Comment: I am using jQuery UI now for a slider. But that does not support dragging the slider handle in touch browsers. jQuery mobile suggests using the range form element. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/forms/forms-slider.html Any suggestions on how I can get a sliding handle to work on mobile browsers?

Comment: Strangely mobile safari seems to implement the attribute, but displays it as text. This causes a bug in my app as i test if the attribute "range" works and if not replace it with a select box. But on iPhone/iPad it's not replaced by the select box, but instead presents a text box with normal keyboard (e.g. input type text).

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/implementing-iphone-slider-unlock-with-input-type-range) it's not implemented in iOS 4.2 and not fully implemented in Android 2.3 (whatever that means). I did test on iOS 4.3 and it looks like it's still not implemented for mobile safari.

`<input type="number"` does not seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

Support for input type="range" has since been added within iOS 5, so you will get the slider in iOS 5, but not before.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Modernizr, the best way to test for input type="range" compatibility would be:

```
var i = document.createElement("input"), safe = false;
        i.setAttribute("type", "range");

        if(i.type !== "text"){
            i.value = ':)';
            i.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;visibility:hidden;';

            if (i.style.WebkitAppearance !== undefined ) {

                document.documentElement.appendChild(i);
                defaultView = document.defaultView;
                safe = defaultView.getComputedStyle &&
                       defaultView.getComputedStyle(i, null).WebkitAppearance !== 'textfield' &&
                       (i.offsetHeight !== 0);

                document.documentElement.removeChild(i);

            }
        } 

        return safe? '<input type="range" />': '<input type="number" />';
```

Hope it helps.